# Embedded software program block, I2C?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, i2c, usart

I have experienced a very strange problem in developing my application for the ST Microelectronics iNemo. My applications consists in:

- Gyroscope reading with SPI
- Accelerometer and Magnetometer (in the same device) reading with I2C
- Attitude estimation algorithm
- PD functions
- Data receiving with USART, with interrupt without DMA
- Sending of logging packet, with USART

The loop is triggered by a timer at 100Hz.
The program works well (I have tested it with some USART debug prints) until I start sending data with the USART: my initial guess was that, since this fact enables the receiving of interrupts, it causes problem with the I2C bus arbitrage mechanism. My guess is derived that when I have succeeded in debugging the problem (that is time dependent), with USART prints, I have detected that the last print is always before the accelerometer of magnetometer prints (the first that I call in my code).
Additionally, If I enable the verbose debug prints via USART that I have mentioned the problem occurs in fewer occasions, while if I disable it and I send only logging packet the problem occurs always and immediately. Anyone can give me an idea of what can be the cause of this problem? Thanks

EDIT: I attach my I2C code:

```
#define DMA_BUFFER_SIZE       196  
#define FORCE_CRITICAL_SEC
/**
 * @brief DMA initialization structure variable definition.
*/ 
DMA_InitTypeDef  I2CDMA_InitStructure;

/**
* @brief Volatile variable definition for I2C direction.
*/ 
__IO uint32_t I2CDirection = I2C_DIRECTION_TX;
void iNemoI2CInit(I2C_TypeDef* I2Cx, uint32_t I2CxSpeed)
{
  I2C_InitTypeDef  I2C_InitStructure;
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

  /* Enable GPIO clocks */ 
 RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB|RCC_APB2Periph_AFIO, ENABLE);

 /* Configure I2C pins: SCL and SDA */
 if(I2Cx==I2C2)
 {
   RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_I2C2, ENABLE);
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =  GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_11;
  }
  else
  {
    GPIO_PinRemapConfig(GPIO_Remap_I2C1,ENABLE);

    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =  GPIO_Pin_8 | GPIO_Pin_9;
  }

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_OD;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);


  /* I2C configuration */
  I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Mode = I2C_Mode_I2C;
  I2C_InitStructure.I2C_DutyCycle = I2C_DutyCycle_2;
  I2C_InitStructure.I2C_OwnAddress1 = 0x00;
  I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Ack = I2C_Ack_Enable;
  I2C_InitStructure.I2C_AcknowledgedAddress =    I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit;
  I2C_InitStructure.I2C_ClockSpeed = I2CxSpeed;

  /* Apply I2C configuration after enabling it */
  I2C_Init(I2Cx, &I2C_InitStructure);

  /* I2C Peripheral Enable */
  I2C_Cmd(I2Cx, ENABLE);

  /* Enable DMA if required */
#if (defined(I2C1_USE_DMA_TX) || defined(I2C1_USE_DMA_RX))
 if (I2Cx==I2C1)
   iNemoI2CDMAInit(I2C1);
#endif

#if (defined(I2C2_USE_DMA_TX) || defined(I2C2_USE_DMA_RX))
 if (I2Cx==I2C2)
    iNemoI2CDMAInit(I2C2);
#endif 


}
void iNemoI2CDMAInit(I2C_TypeDef* I2Cx)
{
  /* Enable the DMA1 clock */
  RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_DMA1, ENABLE);

  /* I2C TX DMA Channel configuration */    
  I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (uint32_t)0;   /* This parameter will be configured durig communication */
  I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralDST;    /* This parameter will be configured durig communication */
  I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = 0xFFFF;            /* This parameter will be configured durig communication */
  I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
  I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
  I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
  I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
  I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Normal;
  I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_VeryHigh;
  I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_M2M = DMA_M2M_Disable;

  if(I2Cx==I2C2)
  {
    I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)I2C2_DR_Address;

#ifdef I2C2_USE_DMA_TX
      DMA_DeInit(I2C2_DMA_CHANNEL_TX);
      DMA_Init(I2C2_DMA_CHANNEL_TX, &I2CDMA_InitStructure);
#endif

#ifdef I2C2_USE_DMA_RX
      /* I2C2 RX DMA Channel configuration */
      DMA_DeInit(I2C2_DMA_CHANNEL_RX);
      DMA_Init(I2C2_DMA_CHANNEL_RX, &I2CDMA_InitStructure);
#endif
  }

  if(I2Cx==I2C1)
  {
    I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)I2C1_DR_Address;

#ifdef I2C1_USE_DMA_TX
      DMA_DeInit(I2C1_DMA_CHANNEL_TX);
      DMA_Init(I2C1_DMA_CHANNEL_TX, &I2CDMA_InitStructure);
#endif

#ifdef I2C1_USE_DMA_RX
      /* I2C1 RX DMA Channel configuration */
      DMA_DeInit(I2C1_DMA_CHANNEL_RX);
      DMA_Init(I2C1_DMA_CHANNEL_RX, &I2CDMA_InitStructure);
#endif

  }
void iNemoI2CDMAConfig(I2C_TypeDef* I2Cx, uint8_t* pBuffer, uint32_t lBufferSize, uint32_t lDirection)
{
  /* Initialize the DMA with the new parameters */
  if (lDirection == I2C_DIRECTION_TX)
  {
    /* Configure the DMA Tx Channel with the buffer address and the buffer size */
    I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (uint32_t)pBuffer;
    I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralDST;
    I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = (uint32_t)lBufferSize;
    if(I2Cx==I2C2)
    {
      I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)I2C2_DR_Address;
      DMA_Cmd(I2C2_DMA_CHANNEL_TX, DISABLE);
      DMA_Init(I2C2_DMA_CHANNEL_TX, &I2CDMA_InitStructure);
      DMA_Cmd(I2C2_DMA_CHANNEL_TX, ENABLE);
    }
    else
    {
      I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)I2C1_DR_Address;
      DMA_Cmd(I2C1_DMA_CHANNEL_TX, DISABLE);
      DMA_Init(I2C1_DMA_CHANNEL_TX, &I2CDMA_InitStructure);
      DMA_Cmd(I2C1_DMA_CHANNEL_TX, ENABLE);
    }
  }
  else /* Reception */
  {
    /* Configure the DMA Rx Channel with the buffer address and the buffer size */
    I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (uint32_t)pBuffer;
    I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralSRC;
    I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = (uint32_t)lBufferSize;

    if(I2Cx==I2C2)
    {
      I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)I2C2_DR_Address;
      DMA_Cmd(I2C2_DMA_CHANNEL_RX, DISABLE);
      DMA_Init(I2C2_DMA_CHANNEL_RX, &I2CDMA_InitStructure);
      DMA_Cmd(I2C2_DMA_CHANNEL_RX, ENABLE);
    }
    else
    {
      I2CDMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)I2C1_DR_Address;
      DMA_Cmd(I2C1_DMA_CHANNEL_RX, DISABLE);
      DMA_Init(I2C1_DMA_CHANNEL_RX, &I2CDMA_InitStructure);
      DMA_Cmd(I2C1_DMA_CHANNEL_RX, ENABLE);
   }
  }
}

void iNemoI2CBufferReadDma(I2C_TypeDef* I2Cx, uint8_t cAddr, uint8_t*    pcBuffer, uint8_t cReadAddr, uint8_t cNumByteToRead)
{

__IO uint32_t temp = 0;
__IO uint32_t Timeout = 0;

/* Enable I2C errors interrupts */
I2Cx->CR2 |= I2C_IT_ERR;

/* Set the MSb of the register address in case of multiple readings */
if(cNumByteToRead>1)
  cReadAddr |= 0x80;

#ifdef FORCE_CRITICAL_SEC
    __disable_irq();
#endif    

#ifdef USART_DEBUG2
    USART1_Printf("FLAG BUSY\r\n");
#endif

Timeout = 0xFFFF;
/* While the bus is busy */
while(I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2Cx, I2C_FLAG_BUSY)){
    if (Timeout-- == 0)
        return;
}

/* Send START condition */
I2C_GenerateSTART(I2Cx, ENABLE);

#ifdef USART_DEBUG2
    USART1_Printf("MASTER MODE\r\n");
#endif

Timeout = 0xFFFF;
/* Test on EV5 and clear it */
while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2Cx, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT)){
    if (Timeout-- == 0)
        return;
}

/* Send LSM303DLH address for read */
I2C_Send7bitAddress(I2Cx, cAddr, I2C_Direction_Transmitter);

Timeout = 0xFFFF;
/* Test on EV6 and clear it */
while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2Cx, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_TRANSMITTER_MODE_SELECTED)){
    if (Timeout-- == 0)
        return;
}

/* Clear EV6 by setting again the PE bit */
I2C_Cmd(I2Cx, ENABLE);

/* Send the LSM303DLH_Magn's internal address to write to */
I2C_SendData(I2Cx, cReadAddr);

#ifdef USART_DEBUG2
    USART1_Printf("BYTE TRANSMITTED\r\n");
#endif

Timeout = 0xFFFF;

/* Test on EV8 and clear it */
while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2Cx, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_BYTE_TRANSMITTED)){
    if (Timeout-- == 0)
        return;
}

/* Configure I2Cx DMA channel */
iNemoI2CDMAConfig(I2Cx, pcBuffer, cNumByteToRead, I2C_DIRECTION_RX);

/* Set Last bit to have a NACK on the last received byte */
I2Cx->CR2 |= 0x1000;

/* Enable I2C DMA requests */
I2C_DMACmd(I2Cx, ENABLE);
Timeout = 0xFFFF;

/* Send START condition */
I2C_GenerateSTART(I2Cx, ENABLE);

Timeout = 0xFFFF;

/* Wait until SB flag is set: EV5  */
while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2Cx, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT))
{
  if (Timeout-- == 0)
    return;
}
Timeout = 0xFFFF;

/* Send LSM303DLH address for read */
I2C_Send7bitAddress(I2Cx, cAddr, I2C_Direction_Receiver);

Timeout = 0xFFFF;

    /* Wait until ADDR is set: EV6 */
    while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2Cx, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_RECEIVER_MODE_SELECTED))
   {
      if (Timeout-- == 0)
        return;
    }
    /* Clear ADDR flag by reading SR2 register */
    temp = I2Cx->SR2;



    if(I2Cx == I2C2)
    {
      Timeout = 0xFFFF;
      /* Wait until DMA end of transfer */
      while (!DMA_GetFlagStatus(DMA1_FLAG_TC5)){
        if (Timeout-- == 0)
            return;
    }
      /* Disable DMA Channel */
      DMA_Cmd(I2C2_DMA_CHANNEL_RX, DISABLE);

      /* Clear the DMA Transfer Complete flag */
      DMA_ClearFlag(DMA1_FLAG_TC5);
    }
    else
    {
      /* Wait until DMA end of transfer */
    #ifdef USART_DEBUG2
        USART1_Printf("END TRANSFER\r\n");
    #endif
      Timeout = 0xFFFF;
      while (!DMA_GetFlagStatus(DMA1_FLAG_TC7)){
       if (Timeout-- == 0)
            return;
    }
      /* Disable DMA Channel */
      DMA_Cmd(I2C1_DMA_CHANNEL_RX, DISABLE);

      /* Clear the DMA Transfer Complete flag */
      DMA_ClearFlag(DMA1_FLAG_TC7);
    }


    /* Disable Ack for the last byte */
    I2C_AcknowledgeConfig(I2Cx, DISABLE);

    /* Send STOP Condition */
    I2C_GenerateSTOP(I2Cx, ENABLE);

    #ifdef USART_DEBUG2
        USART1_Printf("STOP BIT\r\n");
   #endif
   Timeout = 0xFFFF;
   /* Make sure that the STOP bit is cleared by Hardware before CR1 write access */
   while ((I2Cx->CR1 & 0x0200) == 0x0200){
       if (Timeout-- == 0)
        return;
   }

    /* Enable Acknowledgement to be ready for another reception */
    I2C_AcknowledgeConfig(I2Cx, ENABLE);

#ifdef FORCE_CRITICAL_SEC
    __enable_irq();
#endif

}
void iNemoI2CBufferWriteDma(I2C_TypeDef* I2Cx, uint8_t cAddr, uint8_t* pcBuffer, uint8_t cWriteAddr, uint8_t cNumByteToWrite)
{

  __IO uint32_t temp = 0;
  __IO uint32_t Timeout = 0;

  static uint8_t pcDmaBuffer[DMA_BUFFER_SIZE+1];

  /* Set to 1 the MSb of the register address in case of multiple byte writing */
  if(cNumByteToWrite>1)
    cWriteAddr |= 0x80;

  pcDmaBuffer[0]=cWriteAddr;
  memcpy(&pcDmaBuffer[1],pcBuffer,cNumByteToWrite);

  /* Enable Error IT  */
  I2Cx->CR2 |= I2C_IT_ERR;

  Timeout = 0xFFFF;
  /* Configure the DMA channel for I2Cx transmission */
  iNemoI2CDMAConfig(I2Cx, pcDmaBuffer, cNumByteToWrite+1, I2C_DIRECTION_TX);

  /* Enable DMA for I2C */
  I2C_DMACmd(I2Cx, ENABLE);

  /* Send START condition */
  I2C_GenerateSTART(I2Cx, ENABLE);


  /* Wait until SB flag is set: EV5 */
  while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2Cx, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT))
  {
    if (Timeout-- == 0)
      return;
  }

  Timeout = 0xFFFF;

  /* Send LSM303DLH address for write */
  I2C_Send7bitAddress(I2Cx, cAddr, I2C_Direction_Transmitter);

  /* Wait until ADDR is set: EV6 */
  while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2Cx, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_TRANSMITTER_MODE_SELECTED))
  {
    if (Timeout-- == 0)
      return;
  }

  /* Clear ADDR flag by reading SR2 register */
  temp = I2Cx->SR2;


  /* Disable the DMA1 channel */
  if(I2Cx == I2C2)
  {
    /* Wait until DMA end of transfer */
    while (!DMA_GetFlagStatus(DMA1_FLAG_TC4));
    /* Disable DMA Channel */
    DMA_Cmd(I2C2_DMA_CHANNEL_TX, DISABLE);

    /* Clear the DMA Transfer complete flag */
    DMA_ClearFlag(DMA1_FLAG_TC4);
  }
  else
  {
    /* Wait until DMA end of transfer */
    while (!DMA_GetFlagStatus(DMA1_FLAG_TC6));
    /* Disable DMA Channel */
    DMA_Cmd(I2C1_DMA_CHANNEL_TX, DISABLE);

    /* Clear the DMA Transfer complete flag */
    DMA_ClearFlag(DMA1_FLAG_TC6);
  }


  /* EV8_2: Wait until BTF is set before programming the STOP */
  while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2Cx, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_BYTE_TRANSMITTED));

  /* Send STOP Condition */
  I2C_GenerateSTOP(I2Cx, ENABLE);

  /* Make sure that the STOP bit is cleared by Hardware before CR1 write access */
  while ((I2Cx->CR1 & 0x0200) == 0x0200);

}
```

Comment: Your I2C reads are getting stuck. Either you don't use the I2C API in the right way or the hardware is not set up properly.

Comment: Check your I2C waveform on DSO, whether your bit patterns is correct

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have added the code, I think it is ok because is taken from an ST example, but I have attached here, can you give me your opinion about that?

Comment: @Amol I can't, the I2C connection is embedded in a 13x13mm package (iNemo), that integrates both the stmf103, and the sensors. The communication is internal

Answer (score 3):

I see that for some while loops you have a timeout, but for some you don't:

`while ((I2Cx->CR1 & 0x0200) == 0x0200);`

Make all your loops timeout, and also make a note where the error condition occurs (it needs to be investigated - if you don't know the reason, it will come back to haunt you later).

Hardware can be a bit buggy at times, so it completely possible you're doing everything correctly, but it still doesn't work. Check errata (for STM32 I2C and your I2C slaves) for documented bugs.

A few years ago I came across an issue where I2C lines would stay low, and I had to reconfigure pins as GPIO, bit-bang some bits out, and then it I could switch back to I2C operation.

Comment: In addition, it is bad practice to write the semi colon of such loops at the same line. The reader will be unable to determine if the lack of a loop body is intentional, or if it was just a slip of the finger that put the semi colon there.